# C2DM in Android 4.0

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-c2dm

[image]I am using C2DM in my project. I am able to run successfully in Google API 2.2 version in emulator.If I run same code in Google API 4.0 version I am going with an error as Registration error PHONE_REGISTRATION_ERROR and application stops running. Can anyone Please help me resolving this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: show logcat with error please.

Comment: isn't c2dm deprecated? why are you trying it?

Comment: E/C2DM(9091): Registration error PHONE_REGISTRATION_ERROR this is the error

Comment: Please update in your question also please put up the code that gives this error.

Comment: I have uploaded my error

Answer (score 2):

From the C2DM site: https://developers.google.com/android/c2dm/

> C2DM has been officially deprecated as of June 26, 2012. This means
>   that C2DM has stopped accepting new users and quota requests.

Better look for an alternative, such as:
http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/index.html

Answer (score 0):

It has been deprecated in favour of GCM, The official docs say

> Important: C2DM has been officially deprecated as of June 26, 2012.
>   This means that C2DM has stopped accepting new users and quota
>   requests

Whether new users means new devices or projects isn't clear to me, but if it means'devices' then that would explain your error. Try moving to GCM, it seems very good to me

Answer (score -2):

You must reinstall your application.